# Chopping suffixes in variable expansion within a Makefile

Tags: shell, makefile, variable-expansion

As the title states, I have a problem being able to remove suffix from a package name if I need to provide several suffixes (pattern-list)

*Note: I have forced bash usage in the Makefile (`SHELL=/bin/bash`)*

- `DEST_DIR`: Makefile variable
- `PKG_LIST`: Makefile variable, hold a list of folders names (e.g. "packageFsOPT1 packageAdc packageMemOPT2 .....").
  Some of the names might have OPT1 suffix, some other don't.
- `tmp`: folder that is existing and contains the folder packageFs, packageAdc, packageMem.....

Here the part of the Makefile that perform copy from tmp to dest along with the name chopping:

```
for pkg in $(PKG_LIST) ; do \
    cd tmp && tar xzf $$pkg-$(MAJOR).$(MINOR).$(TARGET).tar.gz tmp ; \
    cp -a tmp/$${pkg%OPT1} $(DEST_DIR) ; \
done
```

This is "working", meaning that OPT1 is indeed chopped from packageFsOPT1.
But what I need is to be able to chop different suffixes. In this case OPT1 or OPT2

I tried this:

```
cp -a tmp/$${pkg%+(OPT1|OPT2)} $(DEST_DIR) ; \
```

Which is working if tested directly in console but not within the Makefile (not able to chop => OPT1 stays in the folder name, which doesn't exist => copy fail)

I some kind of stuff like this (but lead to pkg_stripped being empty):

```
pkg_stripped=$(shell echo ${pkg%+(OPT1|OPT2)}) ; \
cp -a tmp/$$pkg_stripped $(DEST_DIR) ; \
```

Does anyone have an idea?

**Edit:** Solutions

Either (using extended global)

```
for pkg in $(PKG_LIST) ; do \
    cd tmp && tar xzf $$pkg-$(MAJOR).$(MINOR).$(TARGET).tar.gz tmp ; \
    shopt -s extglob ; \
    cp -a tmp/$${pkg%+(OPT1|OPT2)} $(DEST_DIR) ; \
done
```

Or (using sed)

See [MadScientist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/939557/madscientist) answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's simpler to use GNU make functions?  Something like this:

```
for pkg in $(patsubst %OPT1,%,$(patsubst %OPT2,%,$(PKG_LIST))) ; do \
    cp -a tmp/$${pkg} $(DEST_DIR) ; \
done
```

This will do the wrong thing (maybe?) if you have names like fooOPT1OPT2 (both will be stripped) but that can be solved as well.

**ETA**

If you need both you'll have to do it in the shell.  You can't use `$(shell ...)` in a recipe: that's a make function so it's expanded by make before the shell is started: it can't operate on the value of any shell for loop variables of course.

I would simply use `sed` for this:

```
for pkg in $(PKG_LIST) ; do \
    prefix=$$(echo "$$pkg" | sed 's/OPT[12]$$//'); \
    cd tmp && tar xzf $$pkg-$(MAJOR).$(MINOR).$(TARGET).tar.gz tmp ; \
    cp -a tmp/$$prefix $(DEST_DIR) ; \
done
```

Comment: Sorry I should have put the complete piece of Makefile. Actually I needed both verbatim and chopped version of pkg in the for loop. Yet Idon't need to have both suffixes a t the same time they will be exclusive.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just out of curiosity, why is pattern-list version (cp -a tmp/$${pkg%+(OPT1|OPT2)} $(DEST_DIR) ; \) not working (in the makefile) ?

Comment: I would say that in your shell you've enabled `extglob` and that's why it's working.  In the shell GNU make invokes, `extglob` is not enabled.  The docs say: _If the extglob shell option is enabled using the shopt builtin, several extended pattern matching operators are recognized_ which implies that if `extglob` is NOT enabled, the extended pattern matching is not recognized.  In my shell command line, for example, the pattern-list you provided doesn't work, because I don't have `extglob` enabled in my shell.

Comment: Indeed extglob not activated by default in Makefile. Initially I though specifying _bash_ as shell in SHELL variable would do the trick but it is not. => `cp -a tmp/$${pkg%+(OPT1|OPT2)} $(DEST_DIR) ; \ ` works now if `shopt -s extglob ; \ ` is added before.

Comment: `extglob` is not enabled by default in bash, you have to enable it.  You probably have it enabled in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` but those are only parsed for interactive shells, not scripts like the ones make invokes.  See the bash docs section **INVOCATION** as the full set of startup processing for bash is quite involved.